# lambda functions vs functors

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor

when I am going through the lambda function, I have seen people comparing lambda with functors & I came across a statement
**users don't have to clutter their code with small functors in some accessible scope.**

My doubt is

1. what is the problem in having small functors in some accessible scope
2. isn't it good idea to have a single function (functor actually) & reuse it across multiple files in our project.

Thanks.

Comment: Function and functor is a too different things: functor is a structure/class that behaves like a function. And lambdas are usually one-time functions and used in one or two places only.

Comment: What do you mean by "some accessible scope" ?

Comment: @WhiZTiM   I took it from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)  , I think he means put it in some header file & use it in different files by including that header filet.

Comment: @m0nhawk do you mean, we can't compare them in any way right ?       & my question is different..

Comment: @Durga It's possible to use one on place of the other (with some limitations of passing and storing). But there is a different choice for various situation: one-time usage - lambda; function - function; and smart function (with parametrisation, statefulness) - functor.

Answer (score 3):

1. it is unnecessary if you have to use each only once. Lambdas usually makes the code more readable, the *function* is defined exactly at the place it is needed.
2. this is not always the case, a function may be called at only one place. Of course if you needed it at different places a functor may be more appropriate.